# Poor performance in phpMyAdmin when using JOIN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

For a specific website I ran the following simple query in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT a.`Nom_ID`
FROM `aa_produse_asbis` a
LEFT JOIN `aa_sku` s ON a.`Nom_ID` = s.`sku`
WHERE s.`sku` IS NULL
```

Where a.`Nom_ID` has about 5.000 records and s.`sku` has about 75.000. Both columns are set as UNIQUE and are varchar(255). The query takes 120+ seconds, but if I browse the website in the mean time, it works perfectly. Also, simple SELECT queries work fine ... but not JOINs. They used to respond very quick but I don't know what's the cause of this poor performance (no column index has been changed).

One more thing: When I try to enter MySQL console (`mysql -u root - p`) I get: `mysql: unknown variable 'asocket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`.

What can be the cause of the poor performance in phpMyAdmin?

LE: The EXPLAIN statement looks like:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  a   index   NULL    Nom_ID  767     NULL    4771    Using index
1   SIMPLE  s   index   NULL    sku     257     NULL    73728   Using where; Using index; Not exists
```

Comment: please update your post to ask a question.

Comment: What do you get if you run EXPLAIN SELECT …? Are the indices properly used?

Comment: @Shi: Using index / Using where; Using index; Not exists

Comment: I am not sure how to read your comment. Can you just properly add the result as detail to your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the fields had different collations. Now it's running fine after using the same collation.